# Node JS returns data from axios

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, promise

I have this function:

```
//=============================================================================
    // Get All Currently Active Members Sessions
//=============================================================================
const axios = require('axios')

const activeInfoURL = 'http://192.168.1.101/api/usersessions/activeinfo'

const activeSessions = async () => {

     return await axios.get(activeInfoURL, { headers: { Authorization: process.env.Authorization } })
    .then(response => {
        response.data.result.forEach((data) => {
            return data.userId
        });

    })
    .catch((error) => {
        console.log('error ' + error);
        res.json({status:`Couldn't reach Arena Gaming Server. Try again later`, result:404})
    });
  };
  exports.activeSessions = activeSessions
```

the response of data.userId is

> 3
>   2

I use it like this in my server.js file

```
setInterval(() => {
    console.log(activeSessions.activeSessions())
}, 10000);
```

It want it to return:

> 3
>   2

every 10 seconds but instead it returns

> Promise { < pending > }

What am I doing wrong here? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not getting any values because you are not *returning* any values. In your first `.then` callback you loop over your data and return the `userId` for each item. But you forgot to return the result from the loop. Instead of using `forEach` use `map` and return the newly created array.

Modify your first `then` from this.

```
.then(response => {
    response.data.result.forEach((data) => {
        return data.userId
    });
})
```

To this:

```
.then(response => response.data.result.map((data) => data.userId))
```

Comment: Perfect. Thank you very much Now I am getting `[ 3, 2 ]` as intended :)

Answer (score 1):

Add `await` keyword before the function call because it is asynchronous.

From the [`async`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function) documentation:

> Asynchronous functions operate in a separate order than the rest of the code via the event loop, returning an implicit Promise as its result.

Like the following:

```
const result = await activeSessions.activeSessions();
console.log(result);
```

And need to remove the `await` from `axios` call - so the function will return a `Promise`:

```
return axios.get(/* call information */);
```

Giving you a similar example:

```js
(async () => {
  const run = async () => {
    return new Promise(r => {
      setTimeout(() => r(2), 1500);
    });
  }
  
  console.log('run without await', run());
  
  const result = await run();
  console.log('run with await', result);
})();
```

I hope that helps!

Comment: thanks i did it but i get undefined now instead of promise pending

Comment: Just updated my answer with remove `await` before `axios` call part. Please take a look.

Comment: here is my code now https://ibb.co/zmvr0Sj and server.js https://i.ibb.co/1bYrZ66/code.png 
i still get undefined ... i don't know what i am missing really

Comment: @mohamedadel Your code looks almost okay. Only thing what you miss is to return the `Promise`. It should be `return axios.get(/* call information */);`, as I have mentioned in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

it should work

```
setInterval(async () => {
    console.log(await activeSessions.activeSessions())
  }, 10000);
```

Comment: thanks, I appreciate it. but i get undefined now instead of promise <pending>.
what am I missing here?